# Select columns from a text file and print it as a list

Tags: python

I have no experience in Python. For a project work, I need to use Python. 
The input file has contents as follows

```
1 ; 35 ; 3 ; 3 ; 22728
2 ; 34 ; 10 ; 1 ; 10773
3 ; 34 ; 10 ; 3 ; 4074
4 ; 55 ; 1 ; 2 ; 151335
5 ; 55 ; 1 ; 3 ; 268476
6 ; 83 ; 19 ; 1 ; 69939
7 ; 55 ; 1 ; 1 ; 9821
8 ; 55 ; 1 ; 0 ; 19124
9 ; 16 ; 0 ; 2 ; 1526077
10 ; 84 ; 13 ; 3 ; 14473383
11 ; 25 ; 35 ; 2 ; 18263375
```

The format is a number,space,semi-colon,space,number,space,semi-colon and so on. 
Now I need a program which extracts second and third number from each and everyline. I
So in the need the output should be

```
35,3,34,10,34,10,55,1,55,1,83,19,55,1,55,1,16,0,84,13,25,35.
```

Please help me with this guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Zaven's answer

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

text = """1 ; 35 ; 3 ; 3 ; 22728
2 ; 34 ; 10 ; 1 ; 10773
3 ; 34 ; 10 ; 3 ; 4074
4 ; 55 ; 1 ; 2 ; 151335
5 ; 55 ; 1 ; 3 ; 268476
6 ; 83 ; 19 ; 1 ; 69939
7 ; 55 ; 1 ; 1 ; 9821
8 ; 55 ; 1 ; 0 ; 19124
9 ; 16 ; 0 ; 2 ; 1526077
10 ; 84 ; 13 ; 3 ; 14473383
11 ; 25 ; 35 ; 2 ; 18263375"""

file = StringIO(text)
iCsv = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
itemList = []
for row in iCsv:
    itemList.append(row[1].strip())
    itemList.append(row[2].strip())

print(itemList)
```

This will contain a list that contains the 2nd and 3rd item from each row.
The StringIO part can be swapped out with an `open('file.txt')` when reading from a file rather than a string.

Comment: Thank you for the code. When I executed the code as you have written, it works. The output is a list as I wished in the question. But when I swapped the StringIO part with open('file.txt'), the following error is shown: IndexError: list index out of range. I swapped the StringIO part as following: file = open('file.txt').

Answer (score 1):

Python has builtin csv library, it has custom delimiters:

```
import csv
    with open('file.txt', newline='\n') as csvfile:
        rd = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ; ')
        for row in rd:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. When executed the following error is shown: TypeError: Delimiter must be a 1-character string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. `input.txt` should be on the same folder as python code.

Code:

```
output_list = []

## read data from input.txt file
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

  ## read line by line
  for line in lines:
    split_data = line.split(';')

    ## append the 2nd and 3rd column into a list 
    output_list.append("," + split_data[1].strip() + "," + split_data[2].strip())

  ## create string from list
  output_str = ("".join(output_list) + ".")[1:]
  print(output_str)
```

Output:

```
35,3,34,10,34,10,55,1,55,1,83,19,55,1,55,1,16,0,84,13,25,35.
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But there is a syntax error in the following line:                                              ## create string from list
  output_str = ("".join(output_list) + ".")[1:]       Could you please correct that? Thanks